# CGI C programming web page is not updating

Tags: c

I am a newbie to CGI programming in C. I was trying to generate a random number and keep displaying on the web-page. I made a program in C compiled it and have place in the path of fedora core /var/www/cgi-bin/rand_mumber.cgi. I can access this cgi page via local host and the results are fine. But, when I try to access the web page from another machine on the network, a problem is seen. The webpage keeps loading the data and finally times out. What my analysis says is that the web-browser will not upload the page until the program has terminated. In the example below, the program is never-terminating. Also, one example of this kind is the local time after Google -search, the local time doesn't keep updating by its own. It needs a refresh click. But my 
requirement is that the page should keep updating constantly not waiting for the completion or a refresh click. As the random number is generated it should be displayed on web-page and then again should read for another random number. This process should keep repeating rather than the web-page waiting for a program termination.

Here is the program, which I compiled and renamed as rand.cgi

Please advice me a method to keep updating and displaying the web-page.
It should constantly keep updating the webpage when the random number is generated. 
It's a never ending program.

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"pthread.h"
#include"unistd.h"

pthread_t tid;

void *print_series_forever()
{
 int n;
 int k = 0;

 while( 1 )
  {
     n = rand()%100 + 1;
     printf("%d",n);     
     k++;
     if ( k == 110 )
     {
       printf("\n"); /** Enter next line **/
       k = 0;

     }
     usleep(100);
  }

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int err;

  err = pthread_create(&tid,NULL,&print_series_forever,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid,NULL);
  sleep(2); 
 return 0;

}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: How did it worked for `localhost`? You need to terminate the program and send appropriate response to browser to show a page. You may have to make use of javascript/ajax to reload the page, to keep showing new numbers.

Comment: You should start with reading about HTTP protocol, CGI scripts and webpages. Otherwise you won't come here with similar questions, which shows, that you don't have absolutely any awareness of these topics...

Comment: just one OT comment, I have seen the output of security camera in format of neverending http response as multipart chunks and browsers (IE, chrome, FF) were able to display that as a video...

Comment: Can you point out to me the sub-section of cgi programming via C where the information can be displayed continuously. That will be well appreciated. Some one said, javascript/ajax will be required. Is there any alternate way other than javascipt/ajax. I am not not aware of these languages.

Comment: To Rohan, Yes, I am wondering how localhost was working?